# How to create empty expanding grid col in expander header

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a custom expander header that will show one text box on the left, and several others on the right, and as the windows grows horizontally the left and right text blocks get further apart.  It feels like this should work, but everything stays left justified.

```
<Expander.Header>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="LeftJustifiedCol" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="EmptySpaceCol" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="RightJustifiedCol" ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding GroupByValue}"></TextBlock>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,5,0"  Text="Net: $0.00"></TextBlock>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="Auto" Name="DeleteEntityBtn" Click="DeleteEntityBtn_Click" >Del</Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Expander.Header>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing WPF isn't rendering the middle column because it contains no content, so it takes up no space in the UI. Perhaps a DockPanel with `LastChildFill="False"` would work better than a Grid

Comment: I added a textblock and assigned it to grid column 1 but no luck.  everything was still left justified.  No luck with the LastChildFill either.